# If $a(s) > 0,b(s) > 0,c(s) > 0$, whether $\int {a(s)ds} \le \int {b(s)ds} \Rightarrow \int {c(s)a(s)ds} \le \int {c(s)b(s)ds} $

Tags: calculus

For an integral operation, we know for a positive constant $c>0$, and $a(s) > 0,b(s) > 0$  if $\int {a(s)ds}  \le \int {b(s)ds} $, we have $\int {ca(s)ds}  \le \int {cb(s)ds} $. However, for a given function ${c(s)}>0$ for all $s>0$, if the following inequality holds?

$\int {c(s)a(s)ds}  \le \int {c(s)b(s)ds} $

Answer (score 1):

$\int {a(s)ds} \le \int {b(s)ds} \Rightarrow \int {a(s)-b(s)ds} \le 0$.

By positivity of the integral you then have :
$\int {c(s)(a(s)-b(s))ds} \le 0$

Finally : $$\int {c(s)a(s)ds} \le \int {c(s)b(s)ds}$$

Comment: Your answer perfectly solves my question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The given inequality does hold. In order to prove this, for any interval $[a,b]$ you can partition $[a,b]$ and pick an $s^*$ on each subinterval, then we are back to the case where $c$ is a constant. Now take the limit as the number of subintervals goes to infinity and we have that
$$\int_a^b c(s)a(s)ds \leq \int_a^b c(s)b(s)ds.$$
Since $[a,b]$ was chosen arbitrarily, then we can take any interval and thus we've proven the inequality you asked about.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this illustration is not very perfect. @Jennifer 's answer is much better. Thanks a again.